# java difference between BufferedReader and InputStream when using socket

Tags: java, sockets, inputstream, bufferedreader

```java
        try (
                InputStream reader = socket.getInputStream();
                OutputStream writer = socket.getOutputStream()
        ) {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[4096];
            int byteLength = reader.read(bytes);
            String message = new String(bytes, 0, byteLength, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

            writer.write("response message".getBytes());
            writer.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

```java
        try (
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                OutputStream writer = socket.getOutputStream()
        ) {
            String message = reader.readLine();

            writer.write("response message".getBytes());
            writer.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I made server socket. It returns response message when it receives message from client socket.
When I use only InputStream (first code), the client socket gets response message.
However when I use BufferedReader (second code), the client socket cannot get response message.

The way I send response message is same.
How I receive message is the only different.

What's wrong with the second code?
What's the difference between them?

Comment: The difference isn't between `InputStream` and `BufferedReader`, it is between `read()` and `readLine()`. You aren't sending lines, so trying to read lines isn't going to work. Add a line terminate to the send.

Comment: I read request message with both.\
But after reading message, I send response message to client socket.\
With the first code, client socket gets response message, but with the second code, client cannot get response message.\

I send the same response message, but only by using first code, client gets response message.

I wonder why the clients cannot receive message when I use second code!

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by the repeated backslashes, but if you aren't sending line terminates you can't read lines.

Comment: I can always read client message with using two codes. After reading client message, I always send message "response message" without line terminates with both of two codes. But the difference is client receive "response message" when server use the first code, and client can't receive "response message" when server use the second code. The difference of reading client message with InputStream and BufferedReader affects whether client can receive the server message "response message". I wanna know the reason. Is the question now clear...?